# Angular : how to exclude the angular app from optimizer

Tags: angular, webpack

For test purpose, I'd like to exclude my angular app from being optimized when running ng build, but at the same time I want the vendor files to be optimized.

I cannot find a way to do that. I can exclude files from being build, but that's not what I'm looking for. Is this possible ?

This is my build command :

`ng build --prod --configuration=deploy`

with :

`"deploy": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "angularApp/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "angularApp/environments/environment.deploy.ts"
                }
              ]
            }`

Comment: what do you mean by optimized?
you can keep the sourcemaps if that is what you are looking for

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer you'll find all here

Comment: I mean setting the "optimization" flag to true in angular.json file, so that my code is minified. But only for the vendor files

Answer (score 0):

use this cmd for building your project

**ng build --vendor-chunk**

--vendor-chunk — extract all vendor (library) code into separate chunk

Comment: Yes, I already use the vendorChunk flag in angular.json and it is set to trure, so I can have the vendor files  in a separate chunk. But what I want is to keep this vendor file minified while my app should not be minified. (that's the "optimization" flag in angular.json)

Comment: can you paste your exact build cmd.